# Is the use of term Measurement appropriate in quantum physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

It may not sound like a physics question, but I think, it is.

When we measure spin of an electron in a certain direction, we are actually, setting it up in that direction. That does not sound like measurement. Wouldn't alignment be more appropriate term for use?

Doesn't the probability wave give chances of aligning (or not aligning) the particle in certain direction, given a specific spin direction prior to measurement. That specific direction also by the way, we have to set beforehand, otherwise, we would not know what it is.

Given the things at quantum level are so tiny, do we even have the capability for pure measurement, without actually changing them? Then why the process is called measurement. Can we get away by saying we are measuring the alignment?

When we run a fan, why don't we say - oh! we measured the direction of air flow, and it is in the direction where the blades are facing?

Comment: I disagree pretty strongly with this question and its premises, but it's not an easy topic. In any case, you might be interest in John Bell's [*Against 'measurement'*](http://www.tau.ac.il/~quantum/Vaidman/IQM/BellAM.pdf).

Comment: I actually don't understand what the actual question is. It seems that you have a purely semantical issue with the word "measurement" describing different processes in classical and quantum physics. When you say "pure measurement, without actually changing them", you already have decided that the quantum version of measurement is somehow "impure". Please make it clearer what the *physics* question here is.

Comment: Pure measurement is - When we measure height of empire state building, we do not change the height as part of measuring process, and we still know it is so many feet. We can do that million times. That is not the case with the spin measurement, i.e. to tell what direction the spin is (or not), you must try to set it in that direction. We can tell the rotation direction of a rotating top, without changing the direction. The question is about difference between measuring, and setting. I guess you know.

Comment: Actually, you can't do it with the empire state building, either, but in practice the limitations imposed on nature to your attempt at a perfect measurement don't matter, so _you_ can ignore them. That doesn't mean that nature does. A measurement, in quantum mechanics, is a physical operation that leaves a record and that is therefor irreversible.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Well we can do with the building by installing a meter next to it, without interacting with it. The light used to compare the two is bouncing of the building anyway whether we are trying to measure it or not. But I get your point of scale. Therefore, it is the size (or quantity) that makes all the difference. Obviously, when what you measure becomes lighter/smaller than the meter itself, then it becomes impossible to measure without inflicting a change.  That is why, I stated, may be in QM, it should not be called measurement.

Comment: My point is that "a measurement" in QM is not something special, it's actually something banal. It's the requirement that something other than reversible unitary dynamics happens. One can apply the same standard to classical measurements, in which case we have to talk about instrument temperature and signal to noise ratios etc..

Answer (score 6):

Measurement is a process in which by help of interactions one quantum entangles the quantum system under study and the environment and by rapidly utilizing decoherence cleans up the "off diagonals" of the entanglement into an apparent collapsed state. After this process, it effectively appears as the wave function of the system has been set to a distinct quantum state.

This process, entanglement of quantum system on a macroscopic state is used so often that it deserves a special name, and that is a measurement. It is a very usefull tool in studying quantum mechanics, since it is absolutely the only way and only process to obtain quantum information to macroscopic world. Nothing more. It obeys the laws of qm as such and should not be mystified. And it is a distinct process from classical measurement and therefore some of your analogies do not work.

To entangle a system with another, interactions are required, however weak. These interactions perform unitary evolution to the system, which is the measurement process. Thus the measurement cannot leave the system into a same state by definition. Also, the measurement is irreversible, since it is impossible to undo the unitary evolution from thermal fluctuations etc. which caused the decoherence (kind of like the entropy always increases).

However, interesting part of the system can be in roughly definite state after measurement. It is sound to talk about measuring a spin of a particle and then further utilize this particle somehere.

When measuring we often measure things like energy, momentum, spin etc. The reason for this is that one usually measured via gauge bosons and they conveniently carry such quantities to far away from the system at study.

Since the measurement process alters the apparent wave function to an eigenstate of the measurement operator, the state will no longer be the same when measuring again with any non-commuting operator. But that is not about measurement as such, but just a fact of qm that Sx and Sy do not commute for example. One just used a measurement which involed unitary evolution of wave function with interaction Hamiltonian containing Sx or Sy. And this setting the state is just basic qm algebra and not so much related to the actual measurement.

All in all, there is nothing mystical about measurement. To conclude, everything would probably be easier if it wouldn't be called measurement.

Comment: What you said in last two lines, is also point of my question.

Comment: A weak measurement doesn't even "clean up the off-diagonals", even though that's a very nice way of putting it. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne after a quick glance to Wikipedia, weak measurement seems like the most trivial quantum computer. There is some pre-praring the state and post-procesing, but the actual measurement (which is the irreversible part) happends to the ancilla state.

Comment: @kpv on the other hand, in quantum mechanics things tend to be named after their classical counterpart. And measurement is quite accurate quantum counterpart to measurement.

Comment: @MikaelKuisma: A weak measurement doesn't completely set the state to a final "result". I don't know how the quantum computing folks feel about "weak computation"? I personally wouldn't rule it out, since weak measurements have lots of interesting properties. It would also be interesting to study the transition between quantum computation and classical computation by increasing a weak interaction along the way.

Comment: @CuriousOne It seems like an interesting concept. What I mean with quantum computing reference (I'm no expert in that) that quantum computing has set of unitary rotations and then a measurement to actually collapse the result. In weak measurement, it seems (correct if I'm wrong), that the weak part is such an unitary operation but so weak that it can be expanded for detailed analysis. And, then like in qc, there is the actual measurement, after the weak part.

Comment: I think there are several interesting questions in here... computing tracks (I don't like "trajectory" in this context much) and ensemble computations with weak measurements. Certainly enough material to keep the field busy for a while. :-)